# How to sort the table of number in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, collections

I want to display the numbers in ascending order by using collections in plsql.

I have code like below. It will display the numbers in unsorted order, but I want to display them in sorted order

```
DECLARE
    TYPE num_asc IS
        TABLE OF NUMBER;
    rec_num   num_asc;
    v_var     NUMBER;
BEGIN
    rec_num := num_asc(10,21,13,14,52,16);
    FOR i IN rec_num.first..rec_num.last LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line (rec_num (i));
    END LOOP;
END;
```

> ```
> Required result:  
> 10  
> 13  
> 14  
> 16  
> 21  
> 52
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use SQL. It's certainly the least code and probably the most efficient approach. Just change the collection type to something we can use in a `table()` function:

```
DECLARE
    rec_num  sys.odcinumberlist;
BEGIN
    rec_num := sys.odcinumberlist(10,21,13,14,52,16);
    for i in (select * from table(rec_num) order by 1)
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line(i.column_value);
    end loop;
END;
```

Answer (score 3):

To sort a collection, you'll need to define the type on a schema level.

```
CREATE TYPE num_asc IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
```

You can use it in a select statement with `ORDER BY` clause.

```
DECLARE
    rec_num   num_asc;
    v_var     NUMBER;
BEGIN
    rec_num := num_asc(10, 21, 13, 14, 52, 16);

    --Sorting rec_num
    SELECT CAST (MULTISET (
        SELECT *
          FROM TABLE (rec_num)
         ORDER BY 1
    ) AS num_asc)
      INTO rec_num
      FROM dual;
    FOR i IN rec_num.first..rec_num.last LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line (rec_num (i));
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Credit goes to Lucas Jellema, who published a couple of articles on this topic.

- [Sorting PL/SQL Collections, the hard way, the intermediate way and the quite simple way (part one)](https://technology.amis.nl/2006/05/31/sorting-plsql-collections-the-hard-way-the-intermediate-way-and-the-quite-simple-way-part-one/)
- [Sorting PL/SQL Collections, the quite simple way (part two: Have the SQL Engine do the heavy lifting)](https://technology.amis.nl/2006/05/31/sorting-plsql-collections-the-quite-simple-way-part-two-have-the-sql-engine-do-the-heavy-lifting/)

Comment: Thank you. is there any other way to get this output without using collections ?

Comment: @GaniGanesh I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "without using collections". Where're you planning to store these numbers? If you're asking about different ways of sorting a collection, then yes, you can look through linked articles, at least three different approaches are described there. Or you can implement a bubble sort yourself (see the answer by BobJarvis).

Answer (score 2):

Can a list be sorted without collection - sure lots of them. Anyway that you can program it. For example an SQL only solution starting with a CSV string:

```
with num_list as (select '10, 21, 13, 14, 52, 16' val from dual )
select v
  from 
      ( select trim(regexp_substr(val,'[^,]+', 1, level)) v 
          from num_list
          connect by trim(regexp_substr(val,'[^,]+', 1, level)) is not null
       )
order by v;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a PL/SQL collection you can just write a little procedure to sort them:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE num_asc IS TABLE OF NUMBER; 

  rec_num  num_asc;
  v_var    number;

  PROCEDURE sort_numbers(pioNumbers IN OUT num_asc) IS
    bSwapped  BOOLEAN := FALSE;
    bRepeat   BOOLEAN := TRUE;
    nTemp     NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    WHILE bRepeat LOOP
      FOR i IN 1..pioNumbers.COUNT-1 LOOP
        IF pioNumbers(i+1) < pioNumbers(i) THEN
          nTemp := pioNumbers(i);
          pioNumbers(i) := pioNumbers(i+1);
          pioNumbers(i+1) := nTemp;
          bSwapped := TRUE;
        END IF;
      END LOOP;  -- i

      bRepeat := bSwapped;
      bSwapped := FALSE;
    END LOOP;  -- bRepeat
  END sort_numbers;

  PROCEDURE print_numbers(pinMsg     IN VARCHAR2,
                          pinNumbers IN num_asc) IS
  BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(pinMsg);

    for i in pinNumbers.first .. pinNumbers.last loop
      dbms_output.put_line(pinNumbers(i));
    end loop;
  END print_numbers;
BEGIN
  rec_num := num_asc(10,21,13,14,52,16);

  print_numbers('Before sort', rec_num);

  sort_numbers(rec_num);

  print_numbers('After sort', rec_num);
END;
```

which produces the following output:

```
Before sort
10
21
13
14
52
16
After sort
10
13
14
16
21
52
```

Best of luck.